# Storing results obtained from Circular Queue in a File

Tags: java

I have designed one Circular Queue program in Java, which will show the elements present inside the queue at a particular time.

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Queue;


public class CircularQueue {

    private int maxSize;
    private int[] cq;
    private int front = -1;
    private int rear = -1;
    private int count = 0;

    private void initialize(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        cq = new int[this.maxSize];
        System.out.println("Circular Queue Initialized with the size of " + cq.length);
    }

    private void enqueue(int element) {
        if (front == (rear + 1) % this.maxSize) {
            System.out.println("Queue is already Full");
            System.out.println("error : Queue Overflows.");
        } else {
            rear = (rear + 1) % this.maxSize;
            cq[rear] = element;
            count++;
        }

        if (front == -1) {
            front = 0;
        }
    }

    private int dequeue() {
        int element = 0;
        if ((front == rear) && (rear == -1)) {
            System.out.println("Queue is already Empty");
            System.out.println("Error: Queue UnderFlows.");
        } else {
            element = cq[rear];
            count--;
            if (front == rear) {
                front = -1;
                rear = -1;
            } else {
                front = (front + 1) % this.maxSize;
            }
        }

        return element;
    }

    private void listQueue() {

        if (rear > front) {
            for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++) {
                System.out.println(cq[i]);
            }
        } else if (rear == front) {
            System.out.println(cq[rear]);
        } else if (rear < front) {
            for (int i = front; i < this.maxSize; i++) {
                System.out.println(cq[i]);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= rear; i++) {
                System.out.println(cq[i]);
            }
        }



    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircularQueue obj = new CircularQueue();
        obj.initialize(2);
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
        System.out.println("");

        obj.enqueue(10);
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
        System.out.println("");


        obj.enqueue(20);
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
        System.out.println("");

//        obj.enqueue(30);
//        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
//        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
//        System.out.println("");

        obj.listQueue();
        System.out.println("");

        obj.dequeue();
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
        System.out.println("");

        obj.listQueue();
        System.out.println("");

        obj.enqueue(10);
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
        System.out.println("");

        obj.listQueue();
        System.out.println("");

        obj.dequeue();
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
        System.out.println("");

         obj.listQueue();
        System.out.println("");

        obj.dequeue();
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
        System.out.println("");

        obj.dequeue();
        System.out.println("count : " + obj.count);
        System.out.println("front : " + obj.front + " : rear : " + obj.rear);
        System.out.println("");


    }
}
```

Now, what I want in my program is that, the moment I want to know the elements present inside the Queue, it should save those elements starting from Front to Rear end of Queue in a File, so that I can check that File anytime.

But, one thing is to be kept in mind that, that File storing elements inside a Circular Queue should be updated every-time.

For Storing this `print.ln()` commands in a file I have code like this:

```
try {
      PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(
          "C://JavaPrograms/ListDeclared.txt"));
      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        out.println(""count : " + obj.count);

      out.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now, problem is that I have to include this Try-Catch Block after every S.O.P statement so as to save in a file. So, is there any other option.

Please help, thanks in advance. :)

Comment: try yourself first and post code if you face any problem.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want to do, or what your problem is. Could you please add: **1)** What you want it to do exactly (an example), **2)** How have you tried to archive that **3)** Anything in your code you consider important to understand the question and help you find a solution

Comment: I have updated the post. Please check again and reply. Thanks :)